# Calculate quickest distance interval with (time, distance) data with SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table of data taken from a GPS device where column 1 is time, and column 2 is distance. Time is the elapsed time from starting an activity and distance is the total distance traveled from a start point.

I'm new to SQL and having trouble formatting a command that allows me to find out the quickest time I traveled a set distance, e.g. What was the quickest km (or 5km, 10km etc)?

For instance if I have a table like this

```
+----------+--------------+
| Time (s) | Distance (m) |
+----------+--------------+
|        0 |            0 |
|       15 |           10 |
|       32 |           22 |
|       40 |           34 |
|       52 |           40 |
+----------+--------------+
```

Is there a way to output the quickest time over which a distance of interest was covered, e.g. the quickest 20m? Obviously the time and distance intervals aren't perfectly spaced, so there will have to be a degree of interpolation.

So in summary,the inputs are the table of data and a distance, and the output is the time in which the distance was covered.

Here is some python that gets the result I want with the data above.

```
#data in format [[time,distance],[time, distance]...]
data = [[0,0],[15,10],[32,22],[40,34],[52,40]]

#calculate the distance and time interval between each data point
start=0
result_array = []
while start < len(data):
    end= start+1
    while end<len(data):
        distance_interval = data[end][1]-data[start][1]
        time_interval = data[end][0]-data[start][0]
        result_array.append([time_interval,distance_interval])
        end+=1
    start += 1

#this is the distance we're interested in
distance_in_question = 20
gap = 9999
quickest_time = 9999

#find the distance_interval closest to the distance in question and report the associated time
for point in result_array:
    distance_interval = point[1]
    gap_test = distance_interval - distance_in_question
    if (gap_test>0) and (gap_test<gap):
        gap = gap_test
        quickest_time = point[0]

#the result     
print quickest_time
```

Comment: Your description is unclear. Please show example data and the desired result.

Comment: I've updated with an example (table formatting gone a bit wild), Thanks.

Comment: Please show the desired result for this example data.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting help - I'm a bit new to all this. I've added some python code that gets the result I'm after. hopefully it explains what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

We want to compare each record with each other (later) record, so we have to join the table with itself:

```
SELECT B.Time - A.Time
FROM MyTable AS A
JOIN MyTable AS B
  ON A.Time < B.Time
WHERE B.Distance - A.Distance >= 20
ORDER BY B.Distance - A.Distance
LIMIT 1
```